# Visual Studio: suppress output in immediate window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

While testing my C# code, I manually assign different values to struct variables in the immediate window of Visual Studio 2019, like `variable = new MyStruct()`.
This works well, but after every assignment the new value is printed. I assign a struct that has a few fields and a lot of public properties, so the immediate window prints the ToString() representation of the new struct and afterwards every single field and property of the struct, which make a total of 73 useless lines in the immediate window.

How can I suppress that output?
I can cheat by putting the assignment in braces `(variable = new MyStruct()).Prop1` and querying a property of the struct, so I get only one line, which is much better, but that's not what I am looking for. I want no output at all, if possible, or at least the usual "expression has been evaluated and has no value.", because that one can be filtered out easily.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the immediate window (*which I love*), how about decorating the struct/class using the `DebuggerDisplay` above the classes in question to give you just the live stats in the Watch windows?

> a total of 73 useless lines in the immediate window.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{" + nameof(GetDebuggerDisplay) + "(),nq}")]
public class MyHugePropertyLadenClass 
{ 
   ...
    /// <summary>
    /// During debugging let us know what we are l@@king at. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The text to show.</returns>
    private string GetDebuggerDisplay()    // Make this public if not shown in immediate
        => $"Viable: {IsViable} Valid: {IsValid} Address: {LocalAddress}";
```

Also not about the Immediate window, if it applies for you...one can remove properties using

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
```

for it prevents the property following it from appearing in the debug window for the class.

The above code I showed, is done in .Net Core so some features may be different. Check out [DebuggerDisplayAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: First, I thought your suggestions were useless because I did not know how to change the value of a struct in the watch windows. But then I tested it and found that I can indeed enter `new MyStruct()` in the Value column of the variable's line... that's great! However, in the immediate window, I can navigate through all previously used commands using the arrow keys, so I don't have to retype long assignments. :-/ Your suggestions are useful though, +1! Unfortunately they don't answer my question.

Comment: I knew it was a one-off suggestion, so I am glad you got some use out of it; ausgezeichnet.